# Where can I find the icon list in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, vue.js, symfony, twig, shopware

How can I add an icon using the sw_icon command.

example :

`{% sw_icon 'head'  %}`

What else can be written instead of 'head'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at https://botschaft.digital/glossar/shopware-6-icons/

Ressources like this are easily found on google if you want in the future :)